# Can you target a list by GUID in rest in Sharepoint 2013 regardless of which site it is in?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

In sharepoint 2013 rest api, I know you can reference a list by GUID, but typically you still have to provide the site that the list is on in the beginning of the rest url when you target by list name. But if you want to target by GUID, is there a way you can provide the site collection URL and the list GUID and then regardless of which site/subsite the list is on, the rest api will be able to locate the list?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could do this using the Search API but I don't know what the search query would be off the top of my head